# google maps , путь между несколькими точками

Tags: android, google-maps

Только начал изучать Android. Нашел в сети как провести путь между двумя тчоками, но не нашел как это сделать с множеством точек.Точки представлены в виде координат(latitude, longitude).

Comment: android studio - ide , редактор для написания кода, изучать ее конечно надо, но даже полностью изучив, вы никогда не узнаете, как провести путь между какими либо точками, потому что это делают с помощью api android.

Comment: Подсказка: путь между несколькими точками состоит их нескольких путей между двумя точками...

Comment: google maps directions api for android - пишете в гугле и там документация с примерами